# selecting any number of elements from n unique elements but not m pairs

Tags: combinatorics, computer-science

I encountered a problem while finding the no. of ways of *selecting any unordered set from n unique elements that should not have m pairs.*

- 1<=cardinality(set)<=n
- pairs are defined as unordered sets of 2 from those n unique elements.
- m pairs are given already.

Comment: This is not clear at all. Are those pairs _given_ or is it forbidden to be able to _find_ $m$ pairs among the selected subset. The latter could just mean the subset must have less than $2m$ elements, or something more strict if the pairs may overlap. In the case the pairs are given (in which case I suppose it means the subset can have at most one element of each given pair), then it is relevant to know if the pairs overlap or not.

Comment: There are m pairs from those n elements given. But we can't include any of those pairs while constructing a set. pairs can overlap, as otherwise is not said.